# se cambia el formato de fecha al crear un exe con Python usando cxfreeze

Tags: date, formato, cx-freeze

Tengo una aplicacion que al ejecutarla desde visual studio code funciona correctamente. El formato de fecha que coloca en un entry esta con el formato DD/MM/YYYY.  Al crear un ejecutable .EXE en windows 10 con cx_freeze  esa fecha que se coloca en el entry se queda en formato MM/DD/YYYY.  Decir que esa fecha se recoge de un calendario recogido en esta funcion:

```
def obtener_fechainicio():
        global b
        ventana_nueva2=Toplevel()
        ventana_nueva2.title("seleccion de fecha de inicio")
        ventana_nueva2.geometry("400x300")
        cal= Calendar(ventana_nueva2, selectmode="day", day=now.day, month=now.month,year=now.year )
        cal.pack(pady=10)
            
        fechadeinicio.set("")
        def grab_date():
            
            b=str(cal.get_date())
            
            ventana_nueva2.destroy()        
            return fechadeinicio.set(b)


        my_button=Button(ventana_nueva2, text="Obtener fecha", command=grab_date)
        my_button.pack(pady=10)

        my_label=Label(ventana_nueva2, text="")
        my_label.pack(pady=10)
```

el retorno "fechadeinicio.set(b)" lo coloco en un entry
Hay alguna manera de decirle a cx_freeze que no me cambie el formato de fecha que tengo establecido?

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya lo resolvi por suerte... aqui dejo el codigo por si a alguien le sirve

```
def obtener_fechainicio():
        ventana_nueva2=Toplevel()
        ventana_nueva2.title("seleccion de fecha de inicio")
        ventana_nueva2.geometry("400x300")
        cal= Calendar(ventana_nueva2, selectmode="day", day=now.day, month=now.month,year=now.year )
        cal.pack(pady=10)
            
        fechadeinicio.set("")
        def grab_date():
            
            a=str(cal.selection_get())
            ventana_nueva2.destroy()
            date_object=datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d')
            modif=date_object.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            fechadeinicio.set(modif)


        my_button=Button(ventana_nueva2, text="Obtener fecha", command=grab_date)
        my_button.pack(pady=10)

        my_label=Label(ventana_nueva2, text="")
        my_label.pack(pady=10)
```